# Toggle button inabilitates Userinterfaceonly protection

Tags: excel, vba, togglebutton

I'm having a really strange problem with a Macro Excel.
So, when opening my workbook I protect every Worksheet with Userinterfaceonly:=true Password:="XXX"
I have been using my program as normally until today.
Today I have introduced a Toggle button to hide the Userform on my worksheet because some of my Userforms are quite big.
I have seen that if i make the userform dissapear, then appear again and clik on any command button, the code that goes to another sheet to change any cell or do anything triggers an Error.
This did not happen before adding this toggle button.

EDIT: I will try to explain better the working of the program. One of the buttons of the Userform goes to another hidden sheet, makes visible some rows (i do not want the user to be able to see those cells full of data), takes some data and come backs to the original sheet to use it.
Until now it has been working perfectly because on opening the workbook i protect every sheet using Userinterfaceonlye:=True so vba can do things like these without triggering errors.

Basically, the line that throws the error is this, when the sheet is NOT VISIBLE.

```
Sheet("2ndSheet").Columns("A1:B2").Entirecolumn.hidden = false
```

As I say, I have been working with this code for months and this exact part of the code never triggered errors. Now, when i make the Userform invisible and then visible using the Toggle button, then try to run the code, it throws this error:

```
Error 1004: cannot assign hidden property of range class
```

The togglebutton works like this, on the active worksheet:

```
Private sub Togglebutton_Click()
If togglebutton = true then
Myuserform.hide
Else
Myuserform.show vbmodeless
End if
End sub
```

Uppon more investigation it has broken the WHOLE program, not only the previous error triggered. I have restored the previous version and i will try to find another way to hide the userforms and not F*CK up my whole program...

FINAL EDIT: I have added a toggle button to the Userform itself which function is to minimize the userform and make it as little as possible. Clicking on it again will maximize the userform and show the user the different buttons. This way my program still works and i am able to make the Userforms small so my users have no problems with it. However, I still do not know why a toggle button that hides the Userform broke my program...

Comment: what error messages do you get?

Comment: It sounds like your code might be relying on `ActiveSheet` which is changing unexpectedly in the middle of your code. It is always a good idea to include the parent Worksheet when using `Range` or `Cells` in your code. If no parent object is given, they default to `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Hi again, so basically the part of the code that triggers the error is when the program goes to another worksheet, unhides some rows in which i have data and tries to copy the data and come back to the previous sheet. The error triggered is 1004, "can not apply the property of hidden " or something like that. It happens when trying to unhide the rows of the other sheet. But, before using the Toggle button, it worked perfectly thanks to Userinterfaceonly:=True...